# R: Bookdown: One chapter per Markdown File (Rmd)

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

In "*[bookdown: Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html)*" Yihui Xie (2017) writes:

> [...] one chapter lives in one R Markdown file [...].
>   Each R Markdown file must start immediately with the chapter title using the first-level heading, e.g., # Chapter Title

For practical reasons, I'm do not want to follow this convention. But other than the warning message (see below), I haven't observed any issues as a consequence of my insubordination. Is it OK to just ignore Xie (2017) and the corresponding warning? If so, why are the rules and warnings there in the first place?

```
Warning message:
In split_chapters(output, gitbook_page, number_sections, split_by,  :
  You have n Rmd input file(s) but only n first-level heading(s). Did you forget first-level headings in certain Rmd files?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you build the book, bookdown merges the separate .Rmd files into a single Rmd file, and then knitr is run on this master file. Where it joins files it inserts a comment to show the start of the next file such as:

```
Content from chapter 1.

<!--chapter:end:index.Rmd-->

# Introduction {#intro}
```

As these comments are just comments, there is no technical reason that the following chapter must start with the # as required.

I suggest this is more of a styling thing, just like it is conventional to indent code, put spaces after a comma etc. One of the greatest benefits of RMarkdown is how easy it is to understand a file without having to know all the syntax, but lacking a title could confuse a potential reader. However, as you said, particular uses might make sense.